# expected value of random uniformly variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, probability

I actually don't really know if this post belongs to this community but I think it is about failure in my code rather than my calculations.(If it doesn't belong here I will move this post to another community)

I got assignment in my Probability course to demonstrate the expected value [image] of the following random variable  [image].

I need to write a code in matlab that getting `N` random real between `[0,1]` and calculating the following value [image] for each [image] and show why the sequence of values converges to the the value [image]

I wrote the following code in matlab:

```
 n = [2^5,2^6,2^7,2^8,2^9,2^10,2^11,2^12,2^13];
 for i=1:9
   X = rand(n(i),1);
   E(i) = sum(sin(X))/n(i);
 end `
```

but the value of E(i) converges to 0.46 instead of the real expected value.

What have I done wrong in my code?

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: Please don’t put up pictures of code. Edit your question and copy-paste the code into it. There is a button on the toolbar that you can press to get it formatted as code. That way we’ll be able to try out your code without having to type it in. Also we’d be able to read it without squinting at that small font in the picture (on a phone I can’t even zoom in enough to read it comfortably). Thanks!

Comment: I don’t see an error in the code. But it can be improved: You can compute the expectation using `mean`. You should pre-allocate `E=zeros(size(n))` outside the loop.

Comment: Your calculations are wrong. The real expected value is 1-cos(1) or approximately 0.46.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right about this one...i've edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is giving the correct answer, you've miscalculated the theoretical expected value. The correct result via the law of the unconscious statistician is

```
Integral[0,1] sin(x) f(x) dx = Integral[0,1] sin(x) 1 dx
                             = -cos(x) evaluated from 0 to 1
                             = -cos(1) - -cos(0)
                             = cos(0) - cos(1)
                             = 0.45969769413186023.
```